# Use any other method insted of <a> links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I need to have a method to do the same use of links.I have buttons in my web sites. (css styled and only colored buttons). I need to have a method to load a page when the button clicked.
as a example: when someone clicked the red button, the instruction page should load. can anyone suggest me a js or jquery function to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use `<a>` links, unless you don't care about accessibility on your site. Links can be styled and look just like buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this JS:

```
location.href = 'http://www.google.com/' //goes to www.google.com
```

So, your full code would look something like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('your_button_id');
btn.onclick = function() {
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com/' //insert your URL here
}
```

---

Of course, you could always wrap the button in an `a` tag instead:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com/'><button type='button'>Click Me</button></a>
```

This method:

- is more SEO and accessibility friendly
- tells more about what the button's actually supposed to do
- activates behaviors certain browsers have for links, like

  - showing where they go in the status bar
  - special highlighting
- works with JavaScript disabled

so it's generally a better idea.

Comment: I tried your code. But following error shows in the console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'click' of null

Comment: @eyeris Well, you have to replace the `id` with your button's `id`, of course. However you should just wrap the button in an `a` tag; it's much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! the error was I was using Jquery since the start so I added the '#' to the start of the button_id. Its now fixed. and I am really thankful. You saved the day.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you would't just style a link (`<a>` tag) to look like a button. This feels like unnecessary use of JavaScript to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

`<input name="" type="button" value="button" onclick="window.location='www.yourdomain.php'"/>`